# in next-auth, how do you get userID on the server side (nextjs 13 app directory)

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm using:

```
    nextJS: 13.1.6
    nextAuth 4.19.2
```

I'm using the new app/ directory, which is still in Beta.

My problem is that I'm trying to retrieve information about the user in a page, then do logic based on that information. For example, to use the userID, and grab extra info from the database (then prerender the page on the server side).

In [..nextauth.js], I've added extra information in the jwt and session callbacks like so:

```
      callbacks: {
        async jwt({token, user}) {
      
           if (user?.id) {
               token.id = user.id
           }
           if (user?.userName) {
               token.userName = user.userName;
           }

          if (user?.fullname) {
            token.fullname = user.fullname;
          }

                      
           return token
        },
        async session({session, token, user}) {
            session.userID = token.id;
            session.userName = token.userName;
            
            session.fullname = token.fullname;

            //I also tried it this way, according to the docs at:
            //  https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks
            session.user.userID = token.id;
            session.user.fullname = token.fullname;

            return session;
        }
      },
```

In the client side, I am able to retrieve data such as userName like this:

```
"use client"; // this is a client component.

import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react"

export default  function LoginPlaceholder() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();


  if(session) {

 console.log(session);
    return <>

      Welcome, {session.userName} 

      <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
    </>
  }
  return <>
    <br/>
    Not signed in <br/>
    <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>
  </>
}
```

However, on the server side, I am unable to retrieve additional information.

```
export default async function EditUsernamePasswordPage(props) {
    const data = await getData();

    //this is how to get session data in the Next.js 13 apps folder
    //https://twitter.com/nextauthjs/status/1589719535363715072?lang=en
    const session = await getServerSession();
    console.log(session);

    return <pre>{JSON.stringify(session, null, 2)}</pre>;    

}
```

Returns data like this (all of the extra information is missing):

```
{
  user: {
    name: 'John Smith Jr',
    email: 'abc@myserver.com',
    image: undefined
  }
}
```

In my [...nextauth].js authorize(credentials) script, I'm returning a user object that looks like this:

```
{
  id: '123456',
  userName: 'myUserName',
  email: 'abc@myserver.com',
  fullname: 'John Smith Jr',
  name: 'John Smith Jr'
}
```

How can I get access to data such as userID on the server side?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, I saw someone try to answer this question yesterday, but his answer is gone this morning.

I wanted to follow up and answer this question, since I the solution.  That person's answer was correct.

You need to call getServerSessions(authOptions); with the authOptions.
If you do not, then getServerSessions() will only return a few basic fields.

```
  import {authOptions} from "@/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]"; 
export default async function EditUsernamePasswordPage(props) {
    const data = await getData();

    //this is how to get session data in the Next.js 13 apps folder
    //https://twitter.com/nextauthjs/status/1589719535363715072?lang=en
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
    console.log(session);

    return <pre>{JSON.stringify(session, null, 2)}</pre>;    

}
```